IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve XML attributes with values containing a colon-char
Intellij IDEA marks XML attributes containing a colon : as error "Cannot resolve symbol":

The inspection symbol  says "Unresolved reference"

How can I tell IntelliJ to accept attributes with : as normal Strings?
Restart, Update, Rebuild, Invalidate Caches, nothing helps.

Colons that appear in names indicate namespace demarcation. Therefore, you can use colons only to specify an XML namespace for a particular name.

It seems like a bug.

@CrazyCoder that would be true for attribute name bar:foo="some", not sure for attribute value. @anton-dementiev try encoding the colon foo="bar&#x3A;baz"

It looks like a bug because I've been using such XMLs since years and it changed just at one day. The schema defines such attributes as row String: <xsd:attribute name="foo" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
Unfortunately using of encoded chars like  &#x3A; is not an option - I work a lot with XMLs with 100500 similar attributes.

There's a TAG findiing on this: https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/qnameids.

Also, this may be of interest.

The issue was due to the plugin CND Language / Jahia Framework Removing the plugin solves the problem. I did a report at their github page

Support from JetBrains helped: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9221-cnd-language--jahia-framework
